# valueOf() in java Returns Object But why hashcode is not there?

Tags: java, string, return-value-optimization

The API for Integer.valueOf("123") returns an object.. So if I'am Writing This

`System.out.println(Integer.valueOf("456"));`
or `System.out.println(String.valueOf(256));`

these should give me the hashcode of the object but instead it printing simple value 456 and 256.

**So can anyone explain me why instead of hashcode i'm getting the value**

Thanks :)

Comment: Why would you expect to get a hashcode? `println` will call `toString()`, which is overridden in both `Integer` and `String`.

Comment: Printing out an object does not give you the hash code. You seem to be confusing Java with some other language.

Comment: but most of the time printing out object gives you the hashcode !

Comment: A very small fraction of the time you get a string including a class name and a hash code, because you've tried to print an object that doesn't override `toString()`.

Comment: yeah That is True.. and that why i asked this question but now i got the answer and knows how to look for these things **Just Started Learning Java**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Integer` and `String` overrides the `toString()` method.

Also The `hashCode` of Integer is the int value of it:

```
/**
 * Returns a hash code for this {@code Integer}.
 *
 * @return  a hash code value for this object, equal to the
 *          primitive {@code int} value represented by this
 *          {@code Integer} object.
 */
public int hashCode() {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you now i saw that in API too .. So basically for every Primitive type Class the toString() Method has been Overridden ..

Answer (score 1):

`Integer` and `String` override `toString()`, which is why you don't get the default implementation of `Object`.

String's toString :

```
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

Integer's toString :

```
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
}
```